# How to show relationship between two different schemas in a conversation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

The problem is that I have two different Schemas that can be put in place of user property in the `Conversation` model, how can I represent this. It could be `Student` who messaged or `User` who sends a message, please note student and user are different models/schema.

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');

  var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    message: { type: String, required: true },
    user: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' /* I want a Student to also be a ref */ }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });

  var model = mongoose.model('Conversation', schema);

  module.exports = { model, schema };
```

How can I better represent or write this Schema/Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mongoose **dynamic references**. This let's you populate from multiple collections at the same time.

You just have to use the `refPath` attribute instead of `ref` on the path of your schema:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    message: { type: String, required: true },
    author: { 
        type: { type: String, enum: ['user','student'] },
        data: { type: ObjectId, refPath: 'author.type' }
    },{
    timestamps: true
});
```

So the `refPath` property above means that mongoose will look at the `author.type` path in your conversation schema to determine which model to use.

So in your queries you can populate the author of a conversation like so:

```
Conversation.find({}).populate('author.data').exec(callback);
```

You can find more info on the [documentation page for population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) (close to the bottom) and also in [this pull request](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/2640).

**Alternative: Mongoose discriminators**

Depending on how related your user and student models are, you could also use [discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) to solve this. Discriminators are a schema inheritance mechanism. Basically they enable you to have multiple models with overlapping schemas on top of the same underlying MongoDB collection.

When you use discriminators you end up having a base schema and the discriminator schema. You could for example make `user` your base schema and `student` a discriminator schema of user:

```
// Define user schema and model
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// Define student schema and discriminate user schema
var studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ level: Number });
var Student = User.discriminator('Student', studentSchema);
```

Now your student model will inherit all paths from user (so it also has the name property) and save documents to the same collection. Because of this it will also work with your references and queries:

```
// This will find all users including students
User.find({}, callback);
// This will also find conversations no matter if the referenced user is a student or not
Conversation.find({ user: someId }, callback);
```

Comment: @seyi-adekoya Did one of the options solve it for you?

Comment: so how do you create a new user with type of student for example, using the refPath solution

Comment: You would create it just like any other model using .create() e.g. User.create() or Student.create() and then you would set the type in the Collection to "User" or "Student" and simply set the id in the data field: Collection.create({author: { type: 'Student', data: '5889d7971442b111ec1a93e8' }});